# Make how to keep the .sh Shell script generated by Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using Make on Windows, would like to debug the make process, is there a way to keep the .sh she’ll script?

Comment: Make doesn't usually create shell script.  It simply invokes the shell and passes the recipe on the command line; the equivalent of `/bin/sh -c 'echo this is a recipe'`.  On Windows it can sometimes create a batch file if you are using Windows cmd.exe instead of an actual shell, since cmd.exe is significantly more limited than POSIX sh.  I don't know of any way to prevent make from cleaning up these batch files.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want this, though: make prints out (assuming you didn't turn it off) exactly what it will run.  There's nothing mysterious going on in the background that's different than what you see on your terminal.